# Splitting String and Changing String to Double

Tags: android, string, split, double

I Have a TextView that contains longitude & latitude and a number separated by a comma(;)
(like-  "41.0819,37.092,123").
I need to split these into longitude and latitude and change it to double (to use it in map).

How do I do that?

i tried this:

```
for (i=0; i<= txtJson.getText().length(); i++){
    if (gotdata[i] != ","){
       gotdata1[i] = gotdata[i];
    }
    else
    {
       break;
    }
}

gotdata1[i+1]= "\0";
txt.setText(gotdata1[i]);
```

Comment: @t_over i am new to android and dont know how to do it.

Comment: And new to programming? Concepts are the same. ( I do not mean offense)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not display any attempt at finding a solution

Comment: try something first. This is trivial, and if you cannot solve this by yourself, you'll be back in 5 minutes with the next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
String[] coords = myString.split(",");
double lat = Double.parseDouble(coords[0]);
double lon = Double.parseDouble(coords[1]);
```

Comment: what do i do if there are 2 coma ..like(123,123,123)?

Comment: There shouldn't be. If you receive a string like the one in the example "41.0819,37.092", you're fine. This is what you should expect from a correct input. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: i have corrected the question

Comment: The answer is still correct, you also now have a coords[2] which contains "123" - whatever that is.

Comment: What is the third value? Can you simply ignore it? If so, my answer is still valid. Just ignore the value in coords[2].